# website load testing Python script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, load-testing

I am after a Python script to help me load test my Google App Engine website. I want to give it a set of URLs and a request rate (would need to use threads) and then measure the response times of my website.

I have had a look at a few solutions but they don't let you set an upper limit for the request rate.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you _really_ want "request rate" and not "concurrency"? Request rate doesn't tell you anything - either the server can serve it, or it over-runs the server and requests get slower and slower till it crashes. Concurrency tells you more interesting information because it actually investigates how many clients you can serve at once, rather than just hammering your server into submission.

Comment: My client wanted to know if our site can serve X requests/sec at a mean response time of Y ms. So I made a Python script to test this. Would concurrency better illustrate this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a python script for this, you want to use the apache tool `ab`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

It is the canonical load testing solution, and will get you great metrics for performance. You can set the request rate, but should really look at the concurrency level which is a far more meaningful statistic.

Comment: actually I *do* need a Python script, because that is the requirements of my client

Comment: why don't you make a python wrapper for ab?

Comment: because my client needs a pure python solution

Answer (score 3):

[Pylot](http://www.pylot.org/) is a versatile load testing tool written in Python. I haven't used it personally, but it seems good.

Comment: yeah I had a look at it, but doesn't seem to support a target request rate.

Comment: it actually does support a target request rate (if you do a little math).  you can specify the target rate per thread.. and the number of threads.